# Css error using bootstrap and millimeter unit for padding

Tags: html, css, padding

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title></title>
        
        
        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <link href="../css/lib/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="padding:2mm;border-bottom:2px solid blue;">
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

I don't have any idea about the negative height of div.

Any advice would be usefull.

**Edit:**

```js
console.log($("#1").outerHeight());
console.log($("#2").outerHeight());
console.log($("#3").outerHeight());
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title></title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <style type="text/css">

  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="1">
    <div id="2">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div id="3">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to say that the browser is not picking up the styles?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you're actually trying to achieve? It's also advisable to avoid inline css styles. Use a stylesheet

Comment: The height of the div is'not zero.
It's negative!

Comment: how did you figured out that?where is exactly it show the negative height ?

Comment: In the box sizes css F12 tab

Comment: -0.024 .................

Comment: it might came from the border-bottom? have you tried to remove it ?

Comment: The height of the div is not a negative value. The height is equal to the padding: 17.1333px. Can you post a screenshot showing the negative value. @beatnik inline styles are perfectly acceptable - especially if OP is showing us a minimal example.

Comment: in my case using Firefox [IMG](https://ibb.co/JrzQVRj)

Answer (score 0):

If You Mean The Margin Using Negative Value Then We Can Use

```html
<div style="padding:5mm;margin-top:-40px;border-bottom:2px solid blue;">
        </div>
```

Here Margin Holds Negative Value To Displace The Object Towards The Direction Opposite to The Normal Movement Path Simply Margin-top If It Holds Negative Value Then It Moves Towards The Top Instead Of Going Down. Did This Fulfill Your Request?

Comment: The main problem is that i have a div container with some other divs inside of it. The height sum of the inside divs doesn't be equal to container height.